# How is Asynchronous code implemented behind the scenes (Java vs JS for example)?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, multithreading, asynchronous

In the case of JS and NodeJS in particular, I know that there is one thread that runs the event loop, and async calls are delegated to the kernel (which might handle it with multi-threading behind the scenes, but that's abstracted for us).

However, what about other languages, like Java/Kotlin?
Is there a similar mechanism to prevent using additional threads? Or is that the only way to go?

In case it is, it makes me wonder, is there a difference in such languages between standard multi-threading and async programming? or is it essentially the same?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Interesting - I read that here https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Though I assume even in the case you've mentioned something has to handle the polling - in order to know when the async action finished, no?

Comment: You need to differentiate between the engine and the JavaScript code. Within an execution context code is executed single-threaded and no two lines of the same context can execute at the same time. the engine can have multiple running contexts (main context, webworkers, workerthreads, …) in different threads, but those contexts are isolated and can share information only in a limited way. The engine might handle IO multithreaded, but everything that runs as JavaScript code isn't threaded in its context.

Comment: Multithreading is also asynchronous programming. Event-driven, sub-processes and multithreading are different concepts of asynchronous programming with different degrease of interaction, concurrencies and isolation.

Comment: @t.niese Interesting, so in that context, would it be correct to say that JS usually handles I/O calls in the event-driven "way" of async programming, whereas Java usually uses multi-threading to achieve the same result?

Comment: The JS engine could handle the IO using threads or event-based, that's not defined. But on the JavaScript side, it is generally handled even driven, because of the single-threaded nature of JavaScript. Being event-based you can read/process multiple IO stream in parallel using e.g. piping. In Java, you usually need to use Threads for that because the FileStreams don't have an event-based API and are thus blocking. (Maybe there are also event-based IO Streams in Java - haven't used it for a while)

Comment: I used [vert.x](https://vertx.io/) to do async stuff in Java.